# Showing details in Kendo Grid using Angular does not seem to work

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am referring to the link here as my reference : http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular

All I want is couple of rows and then when I click I want kendo-grid to expand and show me details about the row:

My html looks like below:

```
   div kendo-grid="importSelectionDetailsGrid"
     k-options={{mainGridOptions}}
     k-data-source={{packages.packages}}
     class="locus-details-grid str-locus-details-grid table-frame">

    <div k-detail-template>   
            <div>
                This is where all the details go                    
        </div>      
    </div>
```

and my angular controller looks like below:

```
 $scope.packages = {
            "packages": [
        { "PackageContents": "54 samples", "CreatedBy": "kdesai@illumina.com", "Createdon": "06 Oct 2016 at 2:46PM", "Size": "3GB" },
         { "PackageContents": "22 samples", "CreatedBy": "kdesai@illumina.com", "Createdon": "06 Oct 2016 at 2:46PM", "Size": "2GB" },
         { "PackageContents": "5 samples", "CreatedBy": "kdesai@illumina.com", "Createdon": "06 Oct 2016 at 2:46PM", "Size": "1GB" }
            ]
        };

        $scope.mainGridOptions = {
            dataSource: $scope.packages.packages,
            dataBound: function () {
                this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "PackageContents",
                title: "Package Contents",
                width: "120px"
            }, {
                field: "CreatedBy",
                title: "Created By",
                width: "120px"
            }, {
                field: "Createdon",
                title: "Created On",
                width: "120px"
            }, {
                field: "Size",
                title :"Size",
                width: "120px"
            }]
        };    

        };
```

It successfully shows the rows but fails to show any details. I also am not able to figure out clearly from the example that what particular part is responsible for rendering the details because example has a lot of options defined which I do not necessarily need.

Comment: Did you have any errors in the console when you expand the row? Did you tried to put a `console.log(dataItem)` before the the `return` inside the  `detailGridOptions` function to check if data is ok ?

Comment: ok for simplicity, I removed dataItem and just hardcoded the details template to show same repeated values on every row. I just needs to see Kendo-Grid to be able to show that it can slide down while clicking on every row and how me 'something' at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I took the linked Kendo/angular example and replaced their main grid with yours(with the syntax tweaked to match their syntax), their detail template with yours, and their controller with yours, and it seems to do what you want.

Working demo:
http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/oxocu

Note: I know nothing about angular, I use jQuery Kendo, though.  That's why I just replaced their code with yours instead of providing an in-depth answer.

To answer your question about the part responsible for displaying the details in their demo: it is the
    `<div kendo-grid k-options="detailGridOptions(dataItem)"></div>`

inside the detail template and the $scope.detailGridOptions definition that does it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. So what I figured is that I am using a version of Kendo from 2014-Q2. Even in your sample if we select the library from Q2-2014, it does not work. However, when we upgrade it to any other version after that, it starts working. Thank you so much for your help